# JavaScript injection in Android webview

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I have written Javascript code that contain callback handler to my android app and inject it from my android code. It fires call back event when we perform play/pause action of video in webview and return event in callback. We are injecting Javascript  code form both plateform (iOS and Android)

But unfortunately in iOS, all event value data is getting but in Android it is showing "undefined"

Below is my JavaScript code that is injecting from Android

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {
            @JavascriptInterface
            public void getEvent(String data) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),    data , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.w("TAGGG", "callBackEvent: " + data.toString() );

        }
    }, "abc");

@Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                tvErrorMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                String scriptThree = "javascript:window.myApp_event =(function() {" +
                        "function notifyApp(event) {" +
                        "var myCallback = console.log(event);"+
                        "abc.getEvent(event);" + // This is callback for Android
                        "}" +
                        "var oExistingEvents = window.myApp_event || [];" +
                        "oExistingEvents.forEach(notifyApp);" +
                        "return {" +
                        "push: function(event) {" +
                        "notifyApp(event);" +

                        "}" +
                        "}" +
                        "})();";
                webView.loadUrl(scriptThree);
            }
```

How can we get that event name that is get in iOS but not in Android?

Comment: So data.toString() is empty?

Comment: @Steven data.toString() print "undefined"

Comment: What kind of data is `event` because I can't understand it from your code